# Log incorrect passwords in Windows 7

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7

Is it possible to log the wrong passwords entered in the Change User login form?
(So actually one or more users are logged in, and the change user form is shown by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, or by using the Start Menu.)

Comment: I hope not. It would be too easy to recover passwords from typos.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible since password attempts aren't stored neither hashed nor in plain text.

Comment: I think it is possible in older versions of Windows by playing around with MSGINA.dll. It's not been supported from Vista onward, though. I'm also not sure if that even applies to the lock screen in the first place.